# A source for learning how to speak or write formaly?

Tags: formality, writing, email

and thanks for helping me. I would like to know if there is a source so I can learn how to speak and write formally, mostly for these topics:

-Sending a formal email to anyone or an organization or a professor

-How to talk formally with a customer, your boss, or someone you find in the streets whom you only want to ask a question

-How to write a formal article

-What are formal phrases.

Thank you and feel free to tell me if I have written anything wrong in this post.

Comment: Requests for resources may better be posted on meta.

Comment: Hi, Mahdy. As it stands, your post currently does not lie within the boundaries of [what we consider acceptable questions here](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in English Stack Exchange. It is therefore very likely that your post will be deleted soon. However, not all hope is lost. I'd personally suggest that you conduct your very own research using Google, something that I assumed you have not done, based on what I've seen from your post. Thank you for participating.

Answer (score 1):

I'll start by trying to correct some of the mistakes in your post.

> Hello guys, and thanks for helping me. I would like to know if there is a source so I can learn how to speak and write formally, mostly for these topics:
>
> -Sending a formal email to anyone or an organization or a professor
>
> -How to talk formally with a customer, your boss, or someone you find in the streets whom you only want to ask a question
>
> -How to write a formal article
>
> -What are formal phrases.
>
> Thank you and feel free to tell me if I have written anything wrong in this post.

There are many sources to teach you how to write formally. The following is a website to get you started: https://www.fluentu.com/blog/business-english/how-to-speak-business-english/

Another way to learn how to speak formally is to watch Youtube videos. There are many that will help you out. This is a good channel to start with: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCVhogXveUAH4vgTp3H5Q1HA

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me and correcting my mistakes.